# same event, same effect, multiple IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events

I am trying to minify this code with a function. I have multiple IDs.

```js
// opening section
$("#id").click(function() {
  if ($("#id2").is(":hidden")) {
    $("#id2").slideDown("fast");
  }); 

  $("#id3").click(function() {
    if ($("#id4").is(":hidden")) {
      $("#id4").slideDown("fast");
    }); 

    $("#id5").click(function() {
      if ($("#id6").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#id6").slideDown("fast");
      });
```

Comment: Why is it `#id` rather than `#id1` like the rest?

Comment: share your html also

Comment: Use common classes and DOM traversal. To show you exactly how, we'd need to see your HTML, as @SanchitPatiyal mentioned.

Comment: this isnt complete or proper code, are you nesting the onclick events ?your first `if ` condition donot have a closing braces

Answer (score 1):

You could assign an attribute to the `#id` element to signify the corresponding `#id2` element and so on:

```
<div id="id" class="click-div-button" data-clickdiv="id2">
```

Then your jquery is simply

```
$(".click-div-button").click(function() {
  var data=$(this).data('clickdiv')
  if ($('#'+ data).is(":hidden")) {
    $('#'+ data).slideDown("fast");
  });
```

This will pick up the correct divs to trigger on due to their class and puck up the right divs to act on based on the attribute.

Comment: I fixed your missing quote. Note that the selector you generate is also missing the `#`

Comment: This was better before the edit - use `.data('clickdiv')` not `.attr("data-clickdiv")`

Comment: $(this).attr('data-clickdiv') should be stored in a variable, so you dont select the same element twice.

Comment: Is this better now? I knew .data was the way to go, I just doubted myself.

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery

```js
// opening section
  
function slideDown(e) {
  var id = $(e.target).attr('id').replace('id','');
      id = id==''?2:parseInt(id)+1; 
  console.log('will slidown this:',id);
  if ( $( "#id"+id ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
    $( "#id"+id ).slideDown( "fast" );
  }  
}
$( "#id" ).click(slideDown);
$( "#id2" ).click(slideDown);
$( "#id3" ).click(slideDown);
$( "#id4" ).click(slideDown);
$( "#id5" ).click(slideDown);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id">1</div>
<div id="id2">2</div>
<div id="id3">3</div>
<div id="id4">4</div>
<div id="id5">5</div>
<div id="id6">6</div>
```

Comment: this is the correct answers. Compared to the other answers this one reusable

Comment: For me, this is too brittle.  It relies on the format of the id.  In this scenario (id,id1,id2) it works, but if you then add `id="id2b"` or any other formatted id, it stops working.

Comment: ie compared with the others, this one is the *least* reusable.

Comment: This places a very strict restriction on what you can name your IDs, it also prevent two buttons from affecting the same `div`. See my answer below. It allows you to name divs however you like and to associate any div with another freely.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `forEach` loop to generate each event.

Because of the inconsistent format (id -> id2) I am creating an object that maps to the next id.

```
const idMatch = {
  id:  'id2',
  id2: 'id3',
  id3: 'id4',
  id4: 'id5',
  id5: 'id6'
};

Object.keys(idMatch).forEach((key) => {
  const nextKey = $('#' + idMatch[key]);
  const currentKey = $('#' + key);

  currentKey.click(function() {
    if (nextKey.is(":hidden")) {
      nextKey.slideDown("fast");
    }
  });
});
```